# vc++ 2010 "array is not a member of std" error

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, stl, c++11

The following bit of C++11 code:

```
std::array<float, 3> A;
```

Gets an error message:

```
array is not a member of std.
```

In Visual Studio, the word "array" is blue, indicating it is a keyword. That is an extension for CLI. I thought I fixed it once before by going to *Properties/C C++/Language* and setting "disable language extensions" to *Yes.* I also have *Properties/General* set to *No Common Language Support*. Still no joy.

How can I make program work disregarding of the visibility of `array` in the editor as a keyword?

Comment: Fixed, as it sounded like you were only concerned about the visible issue of the editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the `<array>` header.

Comment: I figured that out and was trying to delete this question, but you beat me to it. Can't delete now that you've answered. The blue color of "array" threw me off. First spurious squiggles, now spurious blue ink. With CLI turned off, array is not a keyword, but it's red anyway. You sure are helpful, James. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Said "red." Shoulda said "blue." Was half way through editing when my 5 minutes ran out. I just keep getting stupider today. Time to take a break.

Comment: The syntax colorizer will recognize C++/CLI keywords even when C++/CLI is disabled.  The experience is substantially better in Visual Studio 2012, which has semantic coloring (so, you can color types one color, functions another, variables another, etc.).  With the semantic colorization, `array` will be colored as a type if and only if `<array>` is included (I've found that this is most helpful in quickly identifying names that I've mistyped, or missing includes, or incorrect name qualification.)

Comment: Awesome. I am so keen on getting a-hold of 2012. I have to go with the Express version for now, me being semi-retired and all. I have not been able to find out when to expect the desktop version to be available. I understand that originally the answer was going to be "never," so I cannot complain. Someday is way better than never.

Comment: Hey @James, I have an idea. (It can happen.) Suggest to the Senior Error-Message Architect that when a name is not found in a namespace, the message contains, "Hey Bozo, did you include the right header?" - or words to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

**This error can be reproduced even with the 'array' directive on Ubuntu with g++:**

For example, this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::array<int, 5> myints;
    cout << myints.size();
}
```

Compiled and run like this:

```
g++ -o s s.cpp
./s
```

Prints the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This 
file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO 
C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and 
must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
s.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
s.cpp:6:5: error: ‘array’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Solution: compiling it with the compiler option `-std=c++0x`:

```
g++ -o s s.cpp -std=c++0x
./s
```

Then the program correctly prints:

```
5
```